# git clone through ssh returns Permission denied (publickey,password)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ssh, deployment, vlad-deployer

I have production_server and git_repo_server, 
git_repo_server .ssh/authorized keys have  production user id_rsa.pub. 
When I ssh to production_server and make git clone - it works fine, don't ask any password. 
When I try to clone git repo to production_server on my local mashine using ssh I see:

```
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

It looks like ssh should be configured to send commands to remote server. But I don't know how to do it. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Read `/var/log/auth.log`, it may help.

Comment: I see: Apr 23 10:45:01 dev sshd[14635]: Accepted publickey for git from ........ Apr 23 10:45:15 dev sshd[14662]: Failed password for git from <ip> port 37775 ssh2

Comment: I.e. public key is correct, but password is failed. But it looks like password shouldn't be asked as public key is added to authorized_keys

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem was fixed. I added

```
Host * 
    ForwardAgent yes
```

to /etc/ssh/ssh_config

See [ssh-agent tutorial](http://upc.lbl.gov/docs/user/sshagent.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue the probelm was that the user/machine from which I'm accessing Gitosis was not registered as a user in the Gitosis project, and thus access was denied.

1. If you don't have one, generate SSH key in your machine "~/.ssh$ ssh-keygen -t rsa".
2. Use scp command to copy your public key (id_ras.pub) to gitosis_server, to gitosis_admin/keydir.
3. Make sure you rename id_rsa.pub to USER@SYSTEM.pub, USER = the client user, SYSTEM= the client system name.
4. Follow instructions here to add the user (USER@SYSTEM) to the project [https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Git#Adding_users]